# Magical record one-to-many

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'am trying to work with CoreData and Magical record. I have a problem with relationships
So, I have sections and each section should store products
My Section.h

```
@class Product;

@interface Section : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sectionId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Product  *product;

@end

@interface Section (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addProductObject:(Product *)value;
- (void)removeProductObject:(Product *)value;
- (void)addProducts:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeProducts:(NSSet *)values;
```

And Product.h

```
@interface Product : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *descrpt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imgBig;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imgSmall;
```

So, I'm trying to add product to section like this

```
for (int i = 0; i<[sectionResponse count]; i++) {
        _section = [Section MR_createEntity];
        _section.name       = [[sectionResponse valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:i];
        _section.code       = [[sectionResponse valueForKey:@"code"] objectAtIndex:i];
        _section.sectionId  = [[sectionResponse valueForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:i];

        for (int j = 0; j < productResponse.count; j++) {
            if ([_section.sectionId isEqualToString:[[productResponse valueForKey:@"section"] objectAtIndex:j]]) {
                _product = [Product MR_createEntity];
                __product.name    = [[productResponse valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:j];
                _product.descrpt = [[productResponse valueForKey:@"desc"] objectAtIndex:j];

               [_section addProductObject:_product];
            }
        }
    }

    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Can you please help me to understand how to add products and how to retrieve them later? Thanks!

Comment: As an outsider, I love the title and intro. Magical records, core data, and problems with relationships :P

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to set the relationship to One to Many when editing the xcdatamodel file

[image]

2. Second, you should save the data like this

   ```
   [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
       ......... 
       for (int i = 0; i<[sectionResponse count]; i++) {
          _section = [Section MR_createEntity];
          _section.name       = [[sectionResponse valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:i];
         _section.code       = [[sectionResponse valueForKey:@"code"] objectAtIndex:i];
        _section.sectionId  = [[sectionResponse valueForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:i];

   for (int j = 0; j < productResponse.count; j++) {
       if ([_section.sectionId isEqualToString:[[productResponse valueForKey:@"section"] objectAtIndex:j]]) {
           _product = [Product MR_createEntity];
           __product.name    = [[productResponse valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:j];
           _product.descrpt = [[productResponse valueForKey:@"desc"] objectAtIndex:j];

       //   [_section addProductObject:_product];
       //   Instead of "add Product to Section", you should "set the Product's section"  
            [_product setSection:_section];
       }
   }
   }
   }];
   ```

3.So the section is now save as a NSSet. To read the data of a product belong to a section.

```
   //Approach 1
   Section* section = [Section MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"......."] inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];

  NSArray* products = section.products.array; //I assume you use "products" as the name
  //Approach 2
  Product* product = [Product MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"section.sectionID==%@",@"D7689"] inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
```

Feel free to leave me follow up questions

Comment: 1) I created relationship from section to product and set One-to-many
2) When I'm trying save data like this, it is not save, maybe it's not correct? When I save by my it's all ok
3) NSArray* products = section.products.array;
there is no array there

Comment: sorry, late reply. can you post a image of you xdatamodel?

Comment: [First](http://cs628425.vk.me/v628425834/13044/VZdprA4iJoI.jpg)
and
[Second](http://cs628425.vk.me/v628425834/1304e/4y9vaDvXDGQ.jpg)

Comment: section has relationship to products - To many, and product to section has - To one. Right?

Comment: solved my proplem
in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: 
        Section *section = sections[indexPath.row];
        
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"section == %@", section];
        NSArray *products = [Product MR_findAllSortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate];

Comment: sorry, just too busy these two days,,, didn't replay fast enough
nice to hear that solved the problem! :D